# Why is the code printing me only the value of the last pointer in the array of pointers to a string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, scanf

Here is my code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(){
char* a[5] = { "tomer","tomer","tomer","tomer","tomer" };
char t[] = "ppppr";
char* n = &t;
for (int i= 0;i < 3;i++) {
    scanf(" %s",n);
    a[i] = n;
}
for ( int j= 0;j < 3;j++) {
    printf("%s\n", a[j]);
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

What is the reason this outputs three times the last vlaue in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are allocating the memory for new string only once which is

```
char t[] = "ppppr";
```

BTW, there are other problems with in your code.

- you are returning 0 from main but its return type is void instead of
  int
- you should do `char* n = t;` not &t